# Find if this function is continuous or not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Find if this function is continuous or not. $$y= \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty}(1+x)\cdot \tanh(\alpha x)$$

Because $\tanh(\alpha x)=\frac{e^{2\alpha x}-1}{e^{2\alpha x}+1}$$\implies$that it is continuous.So $y$ is continuous.

But the answer is that this function has a first kind discontinuous point at $x_0=0$.Can you explain?

Comment: $\tanh(\alpha x)=\dfrac{e^{2\alpha x}-1}{e^{2\alpha x}+1}$ is by no means a proof of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

You can first find what $y$ is given $x$ fixed. If $x > 0$, $y = 1 + x$; if $x < 0$, $y = -(1 + x)$. This actually shows that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0-} y(x) = -1 \neq 1 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} y(x).$$
Also, this is the only discontinuity of $y$.

---

Hint: When $\alpha > 0$, express $\mathrm{tanh}(\alpha x)$ as $$\mathrm{tanh}(\alpha x) = \frac{1 - e^{-2ax}}{1 + e^{-2ax}}.$$

---

Edit: Basically $f(x;\alpha)$ is continuous in $x$ for each $\alpha$ does not imply $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow \alpha_0} f(x; \alpha)$ is continuous in $x$. Think of $f_n(x) = x^n$ which is continuous on $[0, 1]$. However, $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x^n = \mathbb{I}_{x = 1}$ has a jump discontinuity at $1$.